# String Formatting: Iterate the row values from a csv file

Tags: python, mysql, sql, string, python-3.x

I have a csv file. I want to iterate the rows and produce sql string. I tried the solutions in stackoverflow but could not manage to fix it.

**csv file**

```
rating,product_type,upc,title

Three,Books,a897fe39b1053632,A Light in the Attic

One,Books,6957f44c3847a760,Soumission
```

**python file** starts with the following code

```
path = r'C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\book_crawler\books\items.csv'
file = open(path, 'rt')
```

I tried different version for string formatting. Some of the errors I get:

***IndexError: tuple index out of range***

```
for row in file:
    print ('INSERT IGNORE INTO books_table(rating, product_type, upc, title) VALUES({},{},{},{})'.format(row))
```

***TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting***

```
for row in file:
    print ('INSERT IGNORE INTO books_table(rating, product_type, upc, title) VALUES({0},{1},{2},{3})' % row)
```

***TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting***

```
for row in file:
    print ('INSERT IGNORE INTO books_table(rating, product_type, upc, title) VALUES({0},{1},{2},{3})' % (row,))
```

***TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting***

```
for row in file:
    print ('INSERT IGNORE INTO books_table(rating, product_type, upc, title) VALUES({0},{1},{2},{3})' % tuple(row))
```

Comment: Why create an `insert`?  Just use `load data infile`.

Comment: Start by doing `print(row)`. That will explain to us (and you) where the number of arguments is going wrong.

Comment: Did you actually parse the CSV file?

Comment: You're probably parsing the first line of the csv, use `next()` to skip it, also make sure  `row` isn't empty before processing it. Divide your code into blocks and debug it properly.

Comment: This is the part of my code. I am scraping some data to load mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of what you're trying to do, but to **parse a csv** file and generate `mysql` queries with the csv values, you can use:

```
import csv
csv_path = "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/book_crawler/books/items.csv"
with open(csv_path) as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    # skip the first line
    next(readCSV) 
    for row in readCSV:
        # skip blank lines
        if row: 
            # assign variables
            rating = row[0]; product_type = row[1]; upc = row[2]; title = row[3]
            # surround table and fields with  back-tick ` and values with single quote '
            print ("INSERT IGNORE INTO `books_table` (`rating`, `product_type`, `upc`, `title`) VALUES('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')".format(rating, product_type, upc, title))
```

---

**Output:**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `books_table` (`rating`, `product_type`, `upc`, `title`) VALUES('Three', 'Books', 'a897fe39b1053632', 'A Light in the Attic')
INSERT IGNORE INTO `books_table` (`rating`, `product_type`, `upc`, `title`) VALUES('One', 'Books', '6957f44c3847a760', 'Soumission')
```